# Is this the correct way of extracting data from MySQL database for my site made with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a table called articles in my database. I want to be able to extract the latest articles from there to my homepage. I tried a different number of array_reverse functions but I am not able to get them to work. Here is the code I have so far...

```
include('config.php');
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Subject, Content FROM articles";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $subject = $row["Subject"];
        $content = $row["Content"];
        $Id = $row["Id"];
        echo <<<EOD
        <div style="background-color:white; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 20px">
        <a href="template.php?id=$Id">$subject</a><br>$content</div><hr>   
 EOD;
    }
```

And this is one of the code I've tried which didnt work...

```
$posts = count(mysql_fetch_array($result));
for($i = $posts-1; $i>=0; $i--)
{
    $subject = $row["Subject"];
    $content = $row["Content"];
    $Id = $row["Id"];
    echo <<<EOD
    <div style="background-color:white; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 20px">
    <a href="template.php?id=$Id">$subject</a><br>$content</div><hr> EOD;
    }
```

Also I want to the subjects of my links to be clickable so that when they are clicked they can go to a page where it will display the article according to it's ID. I have successfully implemented that by creating a template.php file and put a link "$subject" as my subject in the homepage. This works but I want to know if this is the correct way of doing this and if there are any better ways to do this...

Thanks and sorry if this has been asked, I did try looking for answers but didn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: How do you know it didnt work?

Comment: Hi, I know because I tried it and it gave me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$posts' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: That means you are having syntax error. I hope you didn't put `EOD;` on a single line alone intentionally. In that case it'll be an error.

Comment: It only works if its by itself for some reason. Anyway, the answer by iijb worked with my initial code. Thanks for your help though. Oh and what do you think about my method of creating links to the article subjects to redirect them to one common template. Is that correct?

Comment: its correct. Its normally done when someone wants to hide the actual referer.

Comment: Stop using the old deprecated [MySQL](http://php.net/mysql) extension and start using the [MySQL Improved](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) extension for improved security and performance.

Comment: I don't actually want to hide anything. I just wanted my articles on the homepage to be displayed on 1 single page if they are clicked. And I wanted to do it in a way in which I didnt have to create an HTML page for every single article that is typed. So this is one method which came to my head and I implemented it. My template has this code and it worked just right.

Comment: include('config.php');
$myurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$id = substr($myurl, 17 );
$sql = "SELECT Subject, Content FROM articles WHERE Id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
$subject = $row["Subject"];
$content = $row["Content"];
echo '<div style="background-color:white; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 30px;">$subject<br>$content</div>'
}

Comment: Thanks Repox, I will look into that. I am in the process of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, Subject, Content FROM articles ORDER By Id DESC";
```

If you need only latest 5 articles then, add any limit for limiting results

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, Subject, Content FROM articles ORDER By Id DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Regards

iijb

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. It did exactly what I wanted and I didn't even have to change my initial code.